# Destroy orphaned polymorphic association in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, polymorphic-associations

I recently created a notifications system using a polymorphic association in my Rails application. All was working well until the system stopped showing notifications for certain users. I realized the culprit was an orphaned notification - where Notification.notifiable_id was returning a non-existent user. Here's a diagram:

[Notification is created on Comment creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFHc0.png)

## User model:

```
has_many Notifications, dependent: destroy
```

So there is still the possibility that The user responsible for creating the notification can delete their account, leaving the Notification record orphaned on one end.

Questions: 
1. How do I delete all notifications where Notification.notifiable_id is not found?

2. How do I prevent this issue from breaking the Notifications system in the future?

I realized after posting this I had misunderstood the polymorphic association. I had actually set up Notification.notifiable to point back to a Comment created by a User, not the User itself.

I fixed issue #2 by modifying the Comment model (as well as other models acting as 'notifiable')

```
    has_many :notifications, as: :notifiable, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For your data fix

   ```
   Notification.all.each do |notification|
     notification.destroy if notification.notifiable.nil?
   end
   ```
2. Looks like you are missing a colon on your `dependent: :destroy`. This would have prevented your Notifications from being properly destroyed when a User record is destroyed.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Any ideas on solving question 2?